# How does MutableMap<String, Any?> pass value to var when I use delegate in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following sample code is from a webpage. I understand that these vars _id, city and country get value by delegate.

I can't understand how map: MutableMap pass value to these vars _id, city and country ?

Do I must pass value of these key to map first ? such as map["_id"]=132L, map["city"]="Wuha" and map["country"]="USA"?

What happened if there is no  map["_id"] ?  will the code `var _id: Long by map` cause error?

```
class CityForecast(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>, val dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var city: String by map
    var country: String by map

    constructor(id: Long, city: String, country: String, dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>)
        : this(HashMap(), dailyForecast) {
        this._id = id
        this.city = city
        this.country = country
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) and [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to understand how delegated property works. Object does not own the delegated property directly. It only owns the delegate. For example, `var _id: Long by map` is actually look like

```
var _id: Long
    get() {
        val value = map["_id"] as? Long
        if (value == null)
            throw Excecption()
        return value        
    }
    set(value) {
        map["_id"] = value
    }
```

> Do I must pass value of these key to map first ? such as map["_id"]=132L, map["city"]="Wuha" and map["country"]="USA"?

No, it is a run-time check, just like `lateinit`.

> What happened if there is no map["_id"] ? will the code var _id: Long by map cause error?

Of course, there will be an exception.

Note that this is **NOT** recommended for normal class. It is designed for JSON deserialization (I still prefer GSON though). It is not recommended because you are creating potential run-time exception which can be avoid, including missing value and type checking.

Also, you should use `mutableMapOf()` instead of `HashMap()` if you does not need `HashMap()` explicitly.