# What are different between MutableMap and Map in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I can't understand What different there are between MutableMap and Map in Kotlin?

The following code is from a sample on https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/weatherapp/data/db/DbClasses.kt

I don't know why val map is designed as MutableMap, I think it should be Map because it's field of database table.

Could you tell me why var map is designed as MutableMap ?

```
class CityForecast(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>, val dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var city: String by map
    var country: String by map

    constructor(id: Long, city: String, country: String, dailyForecast: List<DayForecast>)
            : this(HashMap(), dailyForecast) {
        this._id = id
        this.city = city
        this.country = country
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does MutableMap<String, Any?> pass value to var when I use delegate in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065714/how-does-mutablemapstring-any-pass-value-to-var-when-i-use-delegate-in-kotli)

Answer (score 4):

`MutableMap` is the mutable version of `Map`, so if you use `MutableMap` you can modify, change element values, and so on

For example :

1. Adding new values to element

```
val person = mutableMapOf("Kelvin" to 19)
person["Kelvin"] = 25
println(person) // {Kelvin=25}
```

2. Adding new `key`, `value` pair to the map

```
person["angel"] = 17
println(person) // {Kelvin=25, angel=17}
```

3. Remove element from the map

```
person.remove("Kelvin")
println(person) // {angel=17}
```

You can't do these if you use the immutable version of map which is `Map`

Answer (score 3):

I see your confusion - `val` and `var` define pointer mutability - i.e. `val` always points to the same object in memory - while it doesn't say anything about if that object can or cannot change its properties.
var states that your variable can change/point to different objects.

When you declare your map like this:

```
val cities = mutableMapOf(1 to "Paris", 4 to "Rome", 2 to "Viena", 3 to "Barcelona")
```

then you can add or remove elements in this map, since, it's mutable. But you can't change the pointer to a different collection.

Image if you have two maps representing European cities and US cities:

```
val citiesEu = mutableMapOf (1 to "Paris", 4 to "Rome", 2 to "Viena", 3 to "Barcelona")  

val citiesUS = mutableMapOf(1 to "New York", 4 to "L.A.", 2 to "Dallas", 3 to "Washington")

val myCities = mutableMapOf<Int, String>()
```

which you need to switch according to selected state,something like this:

```
if (code == "US") 
    myCities = citiesUS 
else 
    myCities = citiesEU
```

you won't be able to do this because of val (cannot be reassigned), you'd need to change it into: 
**var** myCities = mutableMapOf()

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is read only. `MutableMap` is mutable. Because `var` can be written a new value, it has to be a mutable variable as delegate property. If you only uses delegate property on `val`, you can use a `Map` instead.

Comment: Do I must assign value to the map first when I  define a map ? I can't assign value to map via construct function,right?

Comment: @HelloCW See [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065714/how-does-mutablemapstring-any-pass-value-to-var-when-i-use-delegate-in-kotli/47066460#47066460)